# Suspend not really suspends Ubuntu 22.04 system

Tags: suspend, power-management, 22.04, fan

I know there are plenty of other people asking about suspend, but my issue doesn't seem to match any other post I've found. When I attempt to suspend (via UI button or physical key), my screen blanks as one would expect, but the fans continue spinning loudly and the case lights all stay on. When I attempt to wake the system up, it is on instantly, suggesting to me that it wasn't really suspended.

All I am seeking is to restore the previous behaviour. On 21.10 and 20.04 the behaviour was that suspend would stop all fans and lights, and resuming would take a few seconds.

`sudo dmesg -T | grep -20 -i suspend | tail -42`
gave no output whatsoever (error codes or otherwise).

For context I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 with the default GNOME DE and kernel 5.15.0-39-generic on a desktop tower PC with and Intel CPU and an AMD GPU in case that's relevant.

I'm not very experienced with Linux, so if anyone could point me in the right direction as to where to even look, let alone fix the issue, I would be very grateful. Also, if a kernel downgrade is what's required, will it come with any other effects? And what is the process?

Comment: Does `systemctl suspend -i` from a terminal show up the same scenario as you mentioned above?

Comment: @starkus
Yes, that command behaves as described above.

Comment: Does `systemctl status suspend.target` give you some error message?

Comment: @starkus Output as follows.

`
○ suspend.target - Suspend
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/suspend.target; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:systemd.special(7)

Jun 25 16:27:07 lightning systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Jun 25 16:27:07 lightning systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
....etc
`

No apparent error message

(Apologies for poor code formatting, backticks not working for some reason)

Comment: Seems to be okay.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the output of `sudo dmesg -T | grep -20 -i suspend | tail -42`

Comment: @Raffa done

That command yielded no output

Comment: What does `sudo systemctl status lightning` tell you?

Comment: If it's up and running you could try to suspend again after stopping the lightning service with `sudo systemctl stop lightning`.

Comment: Your system doesn’t seem to have suspended at all … please do a suspend attempt then immediately afterwards run `sudo dmesg -T | tail -99` and add the output to your question.

Comment: @starkus lightning is not a service, it's just the hostname of my PC.

Comment: @Raffa I have been trying to suspend! That's the whole point. The physical button and the power menu suspend option obviously aren't doing it and I don't know how else to cause my PC to suspend. What other command can I issue to attempt to trigger suspend?

Comment: @Raffa I managed to get it to actually suspend using "systemctl suspend"
How should I share the output of that dmesg query you requested?
I think it doesn't tell much because it is populated with messages from after the resume only? Either way thank you for your help so far and please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not a very satisfying resolution, but the correct suspend behaviour has been restored. I don't know what did it, but I think the fix was that I forced a suspend using the command:

```
systemctl suspend
```

This must have kicked something loose in there, because now the rest of the suspend methods are also behaving properly.

This error had been continuously present since the moment I upgraded to 22.04, so if this is happening to anyone else out there, try the command above and hopefully it restores correct behaviour for you too.
Thank you to [@Raffa](https://askubuntu.com/users/968501/raffa) and [@starkus](https://askubuntu.com/users/1037709/starkus) for your assistance.

Comment: Same problem, didn't work for me.