# System not fully suspending

Tags: 22.04, suspend, power-management

I'm having a problem similar to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/q/1415747/22095), but the solution given there doesn't work for me, so I suspect it is a different issue.  When I tell my laptop to suspend, it blanks the screen and the power light goes to snoring mode, but the fan stays on, the case stays warm, and I think it continues drawing battery power as if it were on.  This happens regardless of whether I suspend by closing the lid or by running `systemctl suspend`.

The really strange thing is that yesterday it was working fine, and I can't figure out what might have changed.  I do think now that the problem might have happened once or twice in the past too -- at least I remember opening it from "sleep" a few times to find it unexpectedly warm and low on battery.  But it certainly didn't used to happen every time, which is what it's doing now.

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 with kernel 5.15.0-60-generic on a Thinkpad T14s.

Comment: This looks like a kernel bug to me. You can report it by `ubutnu-bug linux`.